# How do I install SDL.NET in Visual Studio 2010? (Or any other .NET library)

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to get [SDL.NET](http://cs-sdl.sourceforge.net/) to work in Visual Studio 2010, but am really not sure how to go about installing the library (or creating a custom project or something), and any basic instructions would be appreciated. :)

(Im also trying to install the [Farseer Physics](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics) library and later MOGRE)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever project you want to add the requirement to. Right click the References folder then go to browse and find the .dll you want to add.

To add a source project such as Farseer so that you can look though it while using it. Right click the solution and add the project to the solution. Then right click the References folder for your project then click the projects tab and add Farseer.